# Spring Session Model Attribute Naming Convension

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, session-variables, modelattribute

Declaring session model attribute as:

```
@SessionAttributes ("customer")
```

Controller code is basically to modify the customer object :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testlink", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String testLinkHandler(ModelMap modelMap){
    customerDao.getCustomer(111);
    modelMap.put("customers", customerDao.getCustomers());
    Customer cust = customerDao.getCustomer(115);
    if (cust == null){
        cust = new Customer();
    }
    modelMap.put("customer", cust);
    return "testlink";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/testlink", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String testLinkHandler(@ModelAttribute Customer customer){
    customerDao.save(customer);
    return "redirect:/testlink";
}
```

With above code in `POST` method Customer object is loaded from session & posted new customer name with proper id and hence Editing the Customer works perfectly and updates DB with modified customer Name.

But the moment I change the model variable name and the `@SessionAttribute` name from `"customer"` to say `"customerModel"` or `"customer_model"` or `"model"` it doesn't work anymore and above code inserts a new record in DB.

So the question is, Is there a naming convention that needs to be followed here?

Answer (score 1):

```
public String testLinkHandler(@ModelAttribute Customer customer){ ... }
```

This method expects an object named `customer` to be available for binding. When using `@ModelAttribute` without attributes Spring MVC tries to deduce the name of the model attribute from the method argument name.

Now if you decide to rename your model attribute you either have to

1. Rename the method argument accordingly
2. Supply the name to the `@ModelAttribute`.

As I wouldn't suggest option 1, that leaves option 2.

```
public String testLinkHandler(@ModelAttribute("your-model-name-here") Customer customer){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `@SessionAttribute`, Spring obtains an instance of model attribute from the `session`.

Hence  model attribute field name should match with the session attribute name,in this case `customer`

Answer (score 0):

If you require changing of  the attribute name then you can use :

```
@SessionAttributes (types = {Customer.class})
```

Now, whenever you put your modelClass of the type Customer in spring Model then it would automatically be set in the session.